# Minimal Rotate-Right-Double numbers in base n

Tags: code-golf, sequence, base-conversion

### Task

For a given base \$n \ge 3\$, find the smallest positive integer \$m\$, when written in base \$n\$ and rotated right once, equals \$2m\$. The base-\$n\$ representation of \$m\$ cannot have leading zeroes.

The corresponding OEIS sequence is [A087502](http://oeis.org/A087502), and its base-\$n\$ representation is [A158877](http://oeis.org/A158877) (this one stops at \$n=11\$ because the answer for \$n=12\$ has a digit higher than 9). The OEIS page has some information about how to calculate the number:

> `a(n)` is the smallest integer of the form `x*(n^d-1)/(2n-1)` for integer `x` and `d`, where `1 < x < n` and `d > 1`. `x` is the last digit and `d` is the number of digits of `a(n)` in base `n`.
>
> Maple code:
>
> ```
> A087502 := proc(n) local d, a; d := 1; a := n; while a>=n do
>   d := d+1; a := denom((2^d-1)/(2*n-1)); od;
> return(max(2, a)*(n^d-1)/(2*n-1)); end proc;
> ```

You may output the result as a single integer or a list of base-10 or base-\$n\$ digits.

### Examples and test cases

For \$ n = 3 \$, the answer is \$ m = 32 \$. \$ n = 4 \$ should give \$ m = 18 \$.

$$
m = 32_{10} = 1012_3 \rightarrow 2m = 64_{10} = 2101_3 \\
m = 18_{10} = 102_4 \rightarrow 2m = 36_{10} = 210_4
$$

```
n = 3
m = 32
m (base n) = 1012 or [1,0,1,2]
------------------------------
n = 4
m = 18
m (base n) = 102 or [1,0,2]
------------------------------
n = 10
m = 105263157894736842
m (base n) = 105263157894736842 or [1,0,5,2,6,3,1,5,7,8,9,4,7,3,6,8,4,2]
------------------------------
n = 33
m = 237184
m (base n) = 6jqd or [6,19,26,13]
------------------------------
n = 72
m = 340355112965862493
m (base n) = [6,39,19,45,58,65,32,52,26,13]
```

More I/O examples can be found [on OEIS](http://oeis.org/A087502/b087502.txt).

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. Shortest solution in bytes wins.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,m=1,i=1:i<m and f(n,m,i*n)or(m+m%n*i)/n-m*2and f(n,m+1)or m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVLfa9swEH73X3FkDGxH2aSTJUthLpSyh7Ctg7VvIQzPVTaxSs4k56H957OLQ0tBiLvvvu90P3R4mv6MEU/vwMchuT47yFM//IXsnx308QGSG44p@zHCow9@Knw4jGkiOI/HNDgG@SkXL96H7KY088pX6MfXzbfN/c@7@@ubLwxKrGu0bCWqqiDlLHh54SIUvK51ddp3j3349dBDZKETzHdi7T@FuaR9SRjzdazGVIZleB9rX32Mq1Dja3gpKAiBGrsZD94RmsYA3z9v7uCam1ZxLLL7Bx1sb8dIXby9JTIQhgEdwa2VRnEGKNA2aAyfbQaK60YiP1MUailUa2zTSm0aUjeE60ZzUkglKY9qBcFakWXatsFWcLQoteJCa24ajkQ3KGZWq88PWk0VSHlWEENIpXRrheRaCCuVULYxaGWLaJRGa4ywnKqjeqTcFcU8S2pPOVUUexpFpA1D6uNvV8pzB9W6APB7oCls4w6uLutdwzDGycejo2gfM2WgcVbkHJKPEy0DFqurBZtRsrcLWNKPSSVxu@6SqyJosVuc/gM)

**Input**: base `n`
**Output**: The smallest integer `m` satisfies the requirement.

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Bubbler!*

This is a brute-force search that starts at `m = 1` and works its way up. Will run out of recursion limit if the actual solution is too large.

For each `m`, `i` keeps track of the current power of `n`, which is increased until `i>m`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>90 88 86</s>  85 bytes

A recursive port of the Maple function.

```javascript
n=>(d=1,x=n,g=(a=2**++d-1,b=q=n+~-n)=>b?g(b,a%b):(x=q/a)<n?(x+!~-x)*(n**d-1)/q:g())()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctNDoIwEEDhPaeoCSYzLYjoDhi4Ci0/jYZMBYxpQuDqldXbfO@tf3rtltfnm7LrhzBSYKqhpzzxxIkl0PSQUqk@zRNDM7E6UkaqTWPBJPpqsABPc6ax4ga8uhypRwks5XlgNhcWEAHD6BZgQeJZChaVyO9nlUKxRUJ0jlc3DbfJWWg1xBvveNJ4G4Fxb7GM9vAH) (\$a(3)\$ to \$a(9)\$)

Or, for +5 bytes, a BigInt version:

```javascript
n=>(d=1n,x=n,g=(a=2n**++d-1n,b=q=n+~-n)=>b?g(b,a%b):(x=q/a)<n?(~-x?x:2n)*~-(n**d)/q:g())()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDoIwEADvvKIHTXYpFcV4ARa@QkuBaMhWwJgmBL5e8TaZzLz0Vy/t/Hx/FDvbhZ4CUwWWbpx44mQg0JRxHEtp1eEMTcRyV4xUmXoAk@izwRw8TanGkmvYla99njHGu4JjtJhO@QCIgKF3M7AgcedCsChJPK5/khLFGgnROl7c2F1GN0Cj4bTyhkd9Wntg3Bosoi38AA) (\$a(3)\$ to \$a(50)\$)

Comment: Would it help if `d` has a known maximum value? (Spoiler: it is \$2n-2\$ since \$ d \le \varphi(2n-1) \le 2n-2 \$.)

Comment: @Bubbler Well, it may allow some `exec"my_loop;"*2*n` in Python, but I don't think I can take advantage of it in JS.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 11 bytes

```
∞.ΔxsIвÁIβQ
```

-4 thanks to @Grimmy

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNTKoo9L2w63Oh5blPg///GxgA)

explanation:

```
∞ get all positive numbers
 .Δ find the first number for which:
   xs the number doubled and itself (e.g. 64, 32)
     Iв convert to base input (e.g. [1, 0, 1, 2])
       Á rotate right (e.g. [2, 1, 0, 1])
        Iβ convert back from base input to a number (e.g. 64)
          Q compare to the number doubled (that's in the stack from xs)
```

Comment: Rotate right is a built-in. `¤s¨sš` => `Á`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_Ñ¶ZsU'é}a1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=X9G2WnNVJ%2bl9YTE&input=NA)

```
_Ñ¶ZsU'é}a1     :Implicit input of integer U
_               :Function taking an integer Z as an argument
 Ñ              :  Multiply by 2
  ¶             :  Check for equality with
   ZsU          :  Convert Z to a string in base U
      'é        :    Rotate right (string is converted back to decimal afterwards)
        }       :End function
         a1     :Starting with 1, return the first integer that returns true when passed through that function
```

The `'` trick prevents the `é` method from being applied to U (sidenote: there *is* no `é` method for numbers in Japt), instead applying it to the base-U string, and saves 2 bytes over the alternative `ZsU,_éÃ`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

Simple direct solution. Increments `x` and `d` until we obtain the appropriate answer.

```python
n=input()
j=x=d=2;k=2*n-1
while j%k:j=x*n**d-x;x=[2,x+1][x<n];d+=x<3
print j/k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFAD39xVdDFAk0tZELXTE1Q8gDkqbADWlaWp8fH3FxPlyd36N4@J4GhZtVJZlyanJ@XfMC5gVKq14YxWnrmLwGaeXIfPOyo1QR6musEHV8z2W7N5j6@6NLhW2AnyYXCTzwaYt@ReZBBLDKg2aIf/tCiAGB@Mj6W7XLoQlyGcwD5sEHIHVwM7ALsBrEAJO/As)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + bc, 103 bytes

```bash
for((m=1;2*m!=p;));do((m++));t=$(bc<<<"obase=$1;$m");p=$(bc<<<"ibase=$1;${t: -1}${t::-1}");done;echo $m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxDoAgEAR7X4GEAiQWqJUHjwGFaIEYsTO8HaGh2MxmijE6HtlRhr7swkOpVwKmwffqBsZgD8VwXt6rCDWblBIHo6NVRADxmMHd/Nn8965oFKlyLcS1c1mw2xEQ8Tl1Ds1lS/4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 30 bytes

```
Fdr2Kt*2QVr2hQI!%J*Nt^QdK/JK.q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3y2lyMi7RMsoMKzIKCPQU1HVS8uvJC4wxVvfy1uv8P9/QwMuQwsuQ0suIwMuY2MucyMuYy4TAA)

Uses a similar approach to my [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203151/65425). **Note:** I also used the upper bound of 2n-2 on `d` that @Bubbler mentioned in a comment.

```
(Q)
```

Implicitly initialize Q to be the input

```
Kt*2Q
```

Initialize K to be 2Q-1

```
Fdr2K
```

For d in range(2, 2Q-1):

```
Vr2hQ
```

- For N in range(2, Q+1):

```
J*Nt^Qd
```

--> Set J to N * (Q^d - 1)

```
I!%JK/JK.q
```

--> If J%K==0, print J/K and exit the program

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⊖⊗θηＩ÷⌊ΦＥ×θη∨‹ι⊗θ∨‹﹪ιθ²×﹪ιθ⊖Ｘθ÷ιθ¬﹪ιηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsIwEITvPkWOW4gXD156EotQsLUHXyBtg13IT/NXHz8mFrFdWBa@nRlmmJgdNBMx1moOvg2y5xZMUR4uzuFLQcUHyyVXno9Q6dCLdE1RUDIlTWdRebgy56FWvsIFRw4NKpRBwg2FT1kNm@GJkjsw2UTJw8KdOwdIyS7wxxs9BqHz2yR6Srva93zbq9PvXJqSf4mvah1KWu037mmF@ZQxnuNxER8) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses the OEIS quote plus the additional information provided by @Bubbler in a comment whereby `d < 2n-1`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔⊖⊗θη
```

Calculate `2n-1`.

```
Ｅ×θη
```

Loop `nd + x` from `0` to `n(2n-1)`.

```
∨‹ι⊗θ
```

Ensure `d > 1` by returning `1` if it is not, which is never divisible by `2n-1`.

```
∨‹﹪ιθ²
```

Ensure `x > 1` in the same way.

```
×﹪ιθ⊖Ｘθ÷ιθ
```

Calculate `x(nᵈ-1)`.

```
Φ...¬﹪ιη
```

Keep only those values that are multiples of `2n-1`.

```
Ｉ÷⌊...η
```

Divide the minimum of those values by `2n-1` and output the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 80 bytes

```scala
n=>Stream.iterate(1)(n*_)map(p=>p to p*n-1 find(x=>2*x==x%n*p+x/n))find(_!=None)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/atBLANI8RXiRNPAPZSDIcA)

Takes an integer n, returns an `Option[Option[Int]]` (really a `Some[Some[Int]]`).